# Plotting the density of Cauchy distribution

Tags: r

I have been asked to plot the density of the Cauchy distribution with mean 0, bewteen -5 and 5, and to overlay this with the density of the normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.2. 
And I don't even know where to start.. any help?

Comment: A Cauchy with mean 0? Somebody must be pulling your leg.

Comment: Whoever asked you to do this has no idea what they're talking about. Go back to them and inform them that you need to be given tasks that are **not** impossible.

Comment: Cauchy distribution does **not** have mean or to be precise the mean is *undefined*

Answer (score 7):

Look at the documentation for the Cauchy distribution with `?dcauchy`.  In fact, that's the function which calculates the Cauchy density function at a *location* x0, not a *mean* (as @Dason and @iTech) mention; it is certainly defined for x0=0 though.

The equivalent function for the normal distribution is `dnorm`, and a plot might look like this:

```
x<-seq(-10,10,by=0.1)
plot(x, dnorm(x),type="l")
lines(x, dcauchy(x),col="red")
```

[image: Cauchy dist for x0=0 overlain on a Normal dist.]

Note the `seq` command is somewhat arbitrary: it just creates a vector with evenly spaced values from -10 to 10, at intervals of 1/10.

Good luck on the rest of your homework.

***Update:***

Here's a simpler way using `plot.function`:

```
plot(dnorm, -10, 10, n=1001)
plot(dcauchy, -10, 10, n=1001, col='red', add=TRUE)
```